# custom header depending on webpage

Tags: html, if-statement

I want to include a piece of text under the header image on my page only if the user is looking at the home page and not on any others.

So in English it would be something like

if the webpage is https://hotguidebelize.rezdy.com/ 
  display the graphic and display the text

else if the webpage is https://hotguidebelize.rezdy.com/xxx (where xxx is any value)
  display the graphic

Is it possible to do this in html and how do I test the webpage address?

Comment: no you need php or some other language

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using JavaScript:

```
if (window.location.pathname.length <= 1) { 
    console.log('show home-page-only content'); 
    document.getElementById('yourTextDiv').style.display = 'block';
}
```

This script checks to see if there is anything after the domain name (other than a '/') and if not (you are on the home page), it shows the div 'yourTextDiv' which otherwise is hidden by default e.g. something like:

```
<div id="yourTextDiv" style="display:none;">your home page only content here</div>
```

Note that this script won't work for the newer sites that use a hash to navigate through their pages: e.g. https://hotguidebelize.rezdy.com/#xxx